# SPARK MLilb - Put Products from a Matrix into a Chart using Spark

Tags: data-visualization, apache-spark-mllib, market-basket-analysis

I've a dataset (Basket Market Analysis problem) with the following structure :

```
prod1 prod2 prod4
prod2 prod1
prod3 prod5 prod8 prod1
...
```

I'm trying to identify if exists any algorithm that can me allow to create some data visualization over this matrix (like Network Visualization - prod1 is very connected with prod 2).

Anyone knows a good algorithm to make this visualization?

Thanks!

Comment: Apache Spark doesn't have a Graph visualization system. I already solved your problem using **FPGrowth (or Apriori)** algorithm of Mllib in order to solve the Basket Market Analysis problem and then exporting results data in **gexf** format. This data can be read by **gephi** and so can be visualized.

Comment: @UmbertoGriffo thanks for your respons.But you don't have any packages using Spark to explore data visualization?

Comment: No I don't have. You can try to use [Graphlab](https://dato.com/products/create/open_source.html). It directly support Spark RDD.